# Tensorflow RNN output tensor shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, shapes, recurrent-neural-network

I'm quite new to tensorflow and I can't quite get how to shape tensors so that I would get the output as a single number. Basically, my recurrent network should guess the next number. Instead, with each prediction it returns me a list with five numbers? I guess either one or more of my tensors are misshaped.

My input data is formatted to be around 2000 lists with 5 features each like this:

```
[
  np.array ([
              [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
            ]) 
]
```

This is the code for the RNN:

```
cell_units = 400
batch_size = 5
no_of_epochs = 500

data = tf.placeholder (tf.float32, [None, 5, 1])
target = tf.placeholder (tf.float32, [None, 1, 1])


weight = tf.Variable (tf.random_normal ([cell_units, 5, 1]))
bias = tf.Variable (tf.random_normal([1, 1]))


cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell (num_units = cell_units)

output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn (cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)


output = tf.transpose (output, [1, 0, 2])


activation = tf.matmul (output, weight) + bias


cost = tf.reduce_mean (
                        (
                            tf.log (tf.square (activation - target))
                        )
                      )

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer (learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session () as sess:

    sess.run (tf.global_variables_initializer ())
    no_of_batches = int (len (train_x) / batch_size)

    for i in range(no_of_epochs):
        start = 0
        for j in range(no_of_batches):
            inp = train_x [start:start+batch_size]
            out = train_y [start:start+batch_size]
            start += batch_size

            sess.run (optimizer, {data: inp, target: out})
```

Comment: output of last cell `output[-1]`, if you are only looking for last output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` expects inputs of shape `[batch_size, max_time, ...]`. In your example `batch_size` is dynamic (i.e., unknown) and `max_time` is `5` (i.e., number of time steps.). Naturally RNN's output contains `5` entries, one per input step: `[None, 5, cell_units]`.

As @[Ishant Mrinal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896918/ishant-mrinal) suggested you can select the last output step.

```
weight = tf.Variable (tf.random_normal ([cell_units, 1]))
bias = tf.Variable (tf.random_normal([1, 1]))

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell (num_units = cell_units)
output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn (cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)
# Get the last step (4th index).
output = tf.squeeze(tf.transpose (output, [0, 2, 1])[:,:,4]) # Shape of [batch_size, cell_units].
activation = tf.matmul (output, weight) + bias
```

`activation` has shape of `[batch_size, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful! Though when I runs this code I get a new error:

    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): In[0] is not a matrix  [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Squeeze, Variable/read)]]

Comment: What is source of the error? Which line? I created dummy `output` and I tested the code snippet. Works for me.

Comment: This one:
`activation = tf.matmul (output, weight) + bias`
It works fine while training the model, error only appears when trying to predict the next number...

Comment: Can you share code snippet? `activation` corresponds to model prediction, i.e., next number.

Comment: `with tf.Session () as sess:
       
        sess.run (tf.global_variables_initializer ())
        no_of_batches = int (len (train_x) / batch_size)

        for i in range(no_of_epochs):
            start = 0
            for j in range(no_of_batches):
                inp = train_x [start:start+batch_size]
                out = train_y [start:start+batch_size]
                start += batch_size
                sess.run(optimizer, {data: inp, target: out})
                print sess.run (activation, {data: lol})` Tank you for your help! ('lol' is the same format as train_x)